# Does higher FLOPS mean higher throughput?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, papers, image-net, flops

I understand that FLOPS means floating-point operations per second, and throughput is the number of inputs (for example, images) per second. If a model has higher FLOPS, it means it performs faster.

However, in the article [Container: Context Aggregation Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.01401.pdf), they show that:

[image]

The container has higher FLOPS and less throughput, while the container-light has lower FLOPS and higher throughput.

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of Deeplearning:

- FLOPS: Floating Point Ops per Second
- FLOPs: Floating Point Ops

FLOPS, refers to the number of floating point operations that can be performed by a computing entity in one second. It is used to quantify the performance of a hardware.

FLOPs, simply means the total number of floating point operations required for a single forward pass. The higher the FLOPs, the slower the model and hence low throughput.

This thread on stack overflow might help to get a deeper insight:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498651/what-is-flops-in-field-of-deep-learning